# Binding buttons to textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created this jFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/NkxHD/3/ in which I want to bind buttons to textbox. So if I click '7' I want 7 to be displayed in the textbox. Something like this:

```
function(e){} --
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Can you post some example code directly in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an update](http://jsfiddle.net/NkxHD/6/)

and here is more complete one:

[Click Me](http://jsfiddle.net/NkxHD/8/)

Answer (score 0):

[here is the update](http://jsfiddle.net/gnNY6/1/) I add a class "number" to each number button so that the event will not be fired with other buttons.